# How to enforce Azure AD authentication on IIS server level

Tags: azure, authentication, iis, active-directory, azure-active-directory

Is there any possibility to configure IIS server to enforce Azure Active Directory authentication in hosted application? I don't want to apply any changes to app's code, it would be great to provide this authentication only on server level/layer (configuration IIS). Is this even possible?

EDIT

I have situation like this:

Have many applications from a customers. Have Azure AD and users added  there. I need to provide Azure AD authentication to these applications. Moreover, i shouldn't do anything with code of these applications so i thought that i can try to enforce authentication not on application level but on server level. I've been searching informations about possibility of this method but can't find any (only application scenarios supported by Azure AD https://azure.microsoft.com/pl-pl/documentation/articles/active-directory-authentication-scenarios/  ).  The only thing i have found is Azure Multi-Factor Authentication but i don't think it is helpful.

Comment: Questions asking us to recommend or find a book, tool, software library, tutorial or other off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, **describe the problem and what has been done so far to solve it**.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

We tried to find it, and all that i have found that there is no possibility to enforce AAD authenticatoin on the IIS level and that it should be set up on the application layer which is actually the only one recommended and described process on the sites and in the AAD-related articles. I would say, that it can be even hard from a technological standpoint.

[Reference 1](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/28860669/how-do-i-authenticate-via-azure-active-directory-with-multi-tenant-asp-net-appli)

[Reference 2](http://www.asp.net/identity/overview/getting-started/developing-aspnet-apps-with-windows-azure-active-directory)

Comment: Thank you for your response. How about to register own auth provider on IIS  server? It would be useful in any way to solve my problem?